# Static nested class thread safety - java

Tags: java, multithreading, builder

I have a static "Builder" class inside a class called "MyClass". If I try to create two instances of MyClass using the builder simultaneously from two threads, will it be safe ? Can values set by one thread be assigned to object created by another thread ?

Code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int height;
    private int weight;

    private MyClass(Builder builder) {
        height = builder.height;
        weight = builder.weight;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private int height;
        private int weight;

        public Builder height(int h) {
            height = h;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder weight(int w) {
            weight = w;
            return this;
        }

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that it might be unsafe?

Comment: Hello shadow, how do you intend to use your builder (please provide example code)?

Comment: A static inner class is not static in the sense that is a form of singleton, it simply means its essentially a top level class, and cant implicitly access methods and fields in the enclosing type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I try to create two instances of MyClass using the builder simultaneously from two threads, will it be safe?

If you mean using the *same* instance of `Builder` in both threads then no, but if each thread has its own instance of the `Builder` then you'll be fine.  With this kind of pattern:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass.Builder().height(10).weight(2).build();
```

each `Builder` instance is local to a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got your answer. Just to add to it, of course the builder is not thread safe. In the current shape of your code, changing to the following might make it so though

```
public static class Builder {
    private volatile int height;
    private volatile int weight;
```

Comment: He wants two instances on different thread stacks, no need for volatile in that situation.

Comment: No, if the two instances are created from the same builder instance, he'll need it. I thought that was the question - otherwise there would've been no point in him even talking about thread-safety

Comment: "No if the two instances are created from the same builder instance" - this is nonsense, volatile is only required if two threads are going to share an instance, they wont in his case. He thought a static inner class was static in the sense that it would make Builder a singleton.

Comment: If you read back I said same 'builder instance'. With the same builder instance if you don't see a threading issue, thats your problem. As to what he thought/thinks, I'm not claiming any know-how on that - just said that with a static inner class, there was no question of any thread-safety - its pretty basic

Comment: this is somewhat of a x/y problem here. Sure the answer is correct to the question asked, but considering how you'd use a builder instance this problem just doesn't come up (for pretty much the same reason that the uses of StringBuilder dominate StringBuilder by 10000:1).

Comment: Can I assume you meant StringBuilder over StringBuffer? And yeah, my answer was only to the question originally asked - which by "Can values set by one thread be assigned to object created by another thread ?" can only mean using the same 'builder instance' for setting value in one thread and creating object in another. I just said no and tried to do something that can make the answer yes.